# Influxdb server not listening on 8086

Tags: influxdb

I started the influxdb. The meta server is getting started at 8088 and I am seeing a series of [wal] logs. When I try to connect with the server using `influx` command it throws

`Failed to connect to http://localhost:8086
 Please check your connection settings and ensure 'influxd' is running.`

The server is running in the background. What could be the reason ? I have been writing continuously and then I restarted my server. After restarting I am not able to connect to the server. I also tried connecting after an hour of restarting to make sure it was not due to some startup tasks.

What could be the reason for this ?

Answer (score -1):

The db had huge number of series and it took more than 2 hours for the meta server to be up fully. Later, the http listener was up after the initial start tasks.

Comment: Sounds like you are running InfluxDB 0.8. I would encourage you to think about migrating to 0.10, which does not have the startup re-indexing requirements. It's not a trivial upgrade, however, do read up on the 0.8 to 0.9 and 0.9 to 0.10 migration. We're publishing 0.8 to 0.10 migration docs soon.